# Uso de parâmetros na clausula "in" em um TIBQuery

Tags: delphi

Eu tenho o seguinte comando SQL na propriedade SQL de um componente TIBQuery no Delphi.

Comando SQL utilizado no componente com parâmetros:

```sql
select pro_codigo, pro_nome 
  from produtos 
 where pro_fis_codigo = :fis_codigo 
   and pro_bloqueado in (:bloqueado)
```

Comando SQL sem os parâmetros:

```sql
select pro_codigo, pro_nome 
  from produtos 
 where pro_fis_codigo = 1 
   and pro_bloqueado in (1,2)
```

Existe alguma maneira de utilizar o parâmetro `:bloqueado` conforme exemplo abaixo?

```pascal
Query.PramByName(bloqueado).AsString:= '1,2'
```

Comment: Existem contornos, interessa?

Comment: Sim, tenho interesse em contornos

Answer (score 2):

Como te interessa um contorno, segue:

Ao invés de passar um parâmetro só com tudo que você quer colocar, tente o seguinte.

```delphi
IBQuery1.SQL.Clear;
IBQuery1.SQL.Text := Format('Select pro_codigo, pro_nome from produtos where pro_fis_codigo = :fis_codigo and pro_bloqueado in (%s)',[QuotedStr('ParametroVarChar') + ',' + 'Parametro Numero']);
```

Assim, dentro dos colchetes você vai definir seu parâmetro inteiro.

Answer (score 2):

Não há como fazer o que você deseja utilizando parâmetros.
Parâmetros [não funcionam assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8406591/460775).
Você pode tentar [algumas alternativas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747452/parameters-in-query-with-in-clause), como:

- Alterar o SQL "na mão" conforme resposta do Filipe Fonseca
- Usar tabelas temporárias e fazer um join
- Utilizar uma procedure que [transforma o parâmetro em uma lista](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10294548/460775)
- outras maneiras mais obscuras :)

Answer (score 0):

query := '(1,28,32,88,91,9355)';

```
IBQProduto.Close;
IBQProduto.SQL.Clear;
IBQProduto.SQL.Add('select * from produto pro');
IBQProduto.SQL.Add('where pro.item in ' + query);
IBQProduto.SQL.Add('order by pro.item asc');
IBQProduto.Open;
```

Comment: Poderia explicar sua resposta?